# Reduce the current from a Li-ion battery with 6S 18650 cells and BMS to a motor

Tags: lithium-ion, current-limiting, bms

Beginner in electronics looking for advice. I got a 6S BMS board from AliExpress rated at 25 A. I need to reduce current to 5-6 A. The board goes in a mobile vacuum cleaner, its motor is max. 120 W.

I desoldered 4 MOSFETs but it still pumps ~14 A, with is way too much for the motor. What is the best way to reduce the current to 5 A?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The usual response to overcurrent (overdischarge) by a BMS is to completely cut off the load. I.e. lowering the maximum current of the BMS will only cause it to shut down. That does not sound like what you want. My guess is you are looking for a current limiter separate from the BMS.

Comment: What voltage does the motor expect? What voltage is it getting? Why does it pull too much current? Why are you trying to use a BMS to limit current to the motor? It is intended for protecting the batteries, not the load.

Comment: Motor is 21.6v bms board pushes ~24v. Was thinking about current limiter.. But maybe everything can be solved in BMS more easily.. Will try solution of the gent who offered to replace resistors.

Comment: Why would a 100 W motor pull 14 A at 24 V? How did you measure the 14 A? A BMS doesn't "pump" current, it has an output voltage at the motor side, and the motor determines what current it pulls at that voltage.

Comment: Well I thinking because of quite high load motor pull more amps. To run a vacuum fan. I measured with a clamp meter.

Answer (score 2):

> it still pumps ~14 A,

No it doesn't. A battery doesn't "pump" current. The *load* sets the current (at a given voltage). If you want the load to draw less current, you must change the voltage supplied to it. The BMS cannot change the voltage: it's either on or off. Instead you must add a device between the battery (and its BMS) and the load, that reduces the voltage to limit the current. That device is a "motor controller". For a permanent magnet DC motor, a motor controller is often referred to as an ESC (Electronic Speed Control).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT8xiC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To move the BMS current trip point from 25 to 6 A, you need to increase the current sense resistor(s) by a factor of 25/6 or if the IC isn’t direct sense the current via said shunts, modify the gain of the current sense. Trace out a schematic to tell for sure.

Looks like you have two 3 mΩ 2512 resistors in the top left corner, next to B-, for a total of 1.5 mΩ. You need 6.25 mΩ total. Perhaps 10 and 18 mΩ in parallel is close enough.

I would also solder back the MOSFETs you removed to save some losses.

If you intend to limit the current without tripping, the BMS will not do that for you. I would look for a PTC resistor in series of suitable resistance and knee current.